# Log in window (El Capitan)

Tags: macos, login, preferences, xml

How can I update changes to the Login window (Mac OS X 10.11.3).
When I change settings in the Preferences and then restart computer, there is absolutely no difference.

Is there a XML file with these settings or cache?

Comment: What do you mean by "update changes"?

Comment: :-D well i want to see those changes (refresh the login window)... there is no progress

Comment: What kind of changes did you apply to the login window?

Comment: Display login window as: Name and password... for example

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command in /Applications/Utilities/Terminal:

```
chmod -RN ~/Library/preferences
```

and then restart.